# How to create a mac os x "app" that will open emacs -nw within a terminal and the "opened" file

Tags: macos, text, drag-and-drop

It would be handy to have an "app" style icon (perhaps an Apple Script) that will open emacs in a terminal where one can drop (or open with) a file that is dragged on that icon or with command-O

At the moment the closes I get is to drag the file onto terminal and type in some commands (which works if the terminal is already ready).  I would like to have option of "choosing an app" when I command-O "open" a file from the Finder, e.g., I would like all *.org and *.tex files to open in "emacs -nw" inside a Terminal window (not any GUI emacs).